# Vba, select a dynamic matrix

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic

I have a worksheet which contains a data matrix like the sample below:

[image: example]

This array is dynamically generated, so..I know the coordinates of the top left (non empty) cell, I want to find the coordinates of the top right (non empty) Cell

The first solution is to use the .offset and check each cell to the right if it's not null but I find this way bad. I would like find a better way, more optimized.

Does it exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can use [CurrentRegion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property:

```
Sub test()
    With Range("B5").CurrentRegion            
        MsgBox .Address 'address of entire matrix            
        MsgBox .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Address 'bottom right cell
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Really thx Simoco and Gary =) Last question, is there a "custom .currentRegion" that allows to define the region type ? I mean by example, if my array was filled with Integers and around it there was String cell. Is there a way that I only select the "Integer region" ?

Comment: No, unfortunatelly there is not. There should be some additional logic in code (e.g. loop through values of currentRegion in one row to determine in what column string values starts and ends)

Answer (score 1):

If the data is as you posted (an isolated block starting at **B5**).  Then:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("B5").CurrentRegion
    nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
End Sub
```